# How to zip files with same name but different extension?

Tags: bash, zip

I have a large directory with files like this:

```
file1.txt
file1.meta
file1.csv
file2.txt
file2.meta
file2.csv
file2.abc
```

and I would like to create zip files like:

```
file1.zip
file2.zip
```

I have tried

```
ls -1 ~/TEMP | sed 's/\.[a-z]*//g' | uniq | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -i zip {}.zip ~/TEMP/{}.*
```

But that just gives an error message that the file cannot be fund. The problem is with the wildcard * I guess.

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (file1.zip)
    zip warning: name not matched: /home/user/TEMP/file.*
```

Comment: @Theophrastus The folder has ~ 200000 files with different basenames, 'file' was just an example. I tried to get the unique basenames with `sed 's/\.[a-z]*//g' | uniq`.

Comment: have you tried this. `zip file1.zip file1.*` & `zip file2.zip file2.*`

Comment: for Q in \*;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" "$Q";done

Comment: In what directory are the files to be zipped located? I see an `ls` of the current working directory and an argument to zip of the `~/TEMP` directory.

Comment: @Theophrastus Brilliant. `H=${Q%%.*}` is neat.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, fixed it. same directory in this example. Couldn't I do  `zip /any/path/{}.zip`?

Comment: @Theophrastus why is your comment not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Spinning off [from Jeff's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418372/116858), but not using a list:

```
for fname in *.*; do
    prefix=${fname%.*}
    [ ! -f "$fname" ] || [ -f "$prefix.zip" ] && continue
    zip "$prefix" "$prefix".*
done
```

This loop over all names in the current directory that contains at least one dot character.

The body of the loop extracts the filename prefix by removing the bit after the last dot in the current filename (use `%%` in place of `%` to remove from the *first* dot).  It then tests whether the name was actually the name of a regular file (or a symbolic link to one) and whether the corresponding Zip archive for that file already exists or not.

If the file is a regular file (or symlink to one), and if the archive file does not exist, `zip` is invoked to create the archive.

Answer (score 1):

One way, in bash (since you tagged it):

1. Gather the list of filename prefixes into an associative array:

   ```
   declare -A prefixes
   for f in *; do prefixes[${f%%.*}]=1; done
   ```
2. Loop through the prefixes and create the zip files:

   ```
   for p in "${!prefixes[@]}"; do zip "$p" "$p".*; done
   ```