# Terminal command to add a directory to many existing zip files

Tags: command-line, terminal, zip

I am using the below command in Terminal, found here from this answer by @Theophrastus to zip all *.html and *.js files with the same name, while retaining the name of those paired files.

[How to zip files with same name but different extension?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417163/how-to-zip-files-with-same-name-but-different-extension)

```
for Q in *;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" "$Q";done
```

I would like to also have a folder called images included in the zip file, but do not understand what the command above does.

Structure is

```
zipping

|-   images
      bitmap1.jpg
      bitmap2.png

file1.html
file1.js
file2.html
file2.js
file3.html
file3.js
file4.html
file4.js
file5.html
file5.js
```

Once completed the zip files should have the same name they started with, which is the name that the html and js files share.

Comment: check out the `{}` formatting button to format code separately; it makes it much more readable. Thanks!

Comment: Try `for file in *.zip ; do zip -ur "$file" images ; done`

Comment: I'm being misled by the introduction in the question; is there anything about *matching* or *paired* filenames that are important to you?

Comment: Just that the files being zipped initially are an html file that has a js file with the same name.

Comment: Bodo's comment would fix the zip files after-the-fact; are you interested in creating them with the `images` directory there *initially*?

Comment: @SusanForman I don't understand your last comment. If you have some requirement how to initially create the zip files you should edit your question to describe what you want.

Comment: @SusanForman Do you mean something like this? `for Q in *.html;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" "$Q" "${H}.js" images ;done`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify wildcards as the zip file argument for the `zip` command because the shell would replace this with multiple file names. Instead you can use a loop to process multiple zip files one by one.

```
for file in *.zip
do
    zip -ur "$file" images
done
```

or in one line

```
for file in *.zip ; do zip -ur "$file" images ; done
```

Comment: or initially with `for Q in *;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" images "$Q";done`

Comment: That also works, Jeff Schaller. The way that Animate CC publishes canvas files, is that there is only an images folder, if there are bitmaps.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon.  for Q in *;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" images "$Q";done moves the html and js file to a newly created images folder in the zip, breaking the path to the bitmap in the images folder.

Comment: @SusanForman Please edit your question to show an example which files and folders you originally have, what should be the contents of the ZIP file(s) and how the ZIP file(s) should be named.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the solution Bodo. Being a 2 part command in Terminal is actually ideal, as Animate CC only creates an image folder if there are imported bitmaps. All vector Animate content, no images folder.

Comment: @SusanForman It is still not completely clear for me. Do you want to create `file1.zip` containing `file1.html`, `file1.js` and `images/*` (i.e. all files in `images`) and `file2.zip` containing `file2.html`, `file2.js` and `images/*` etc? (This would mean all ZIP files contain all image files.)

Comment: Yes. You solution works perfectly. I run the first command. Then if there is an images folder, I run your command, and the images folder is inserted into the zip files created by the first command, which is, as noted above: for Q in *;do H=${Q%%.*};zip "${H}.zip" "$Q";done