# Zip files together sharing common prefix

Tags: bash, zip

I have a directory with scsv files like this:

```
file1.scsv
file1_key.scsv
file1_flag.scsv
file1_typelist.scsv
files2.scsv
filass3.scsv
file4.scsv
file4_key.scsv
file4_flag.scsv
file5.scsv
```

i.e. you have `file1`, `files2`, `filass3`, etc. as prefixes. the prefix length varies quite alot, so i can't rely on that. the suffixes `_key`, `_flag` and `_typelist` are always the same and wont change.

and i would like to zip them like this:

```bsh
file1.zip 
     #contains 
     file1.scsv
     file1_key.scsv
     file1_flag.scsv
     file1_typelist.scsv
files2.zip 
     #contains 
     files2.scsv
filass3.zip 
     #contains 
     filass3.scsv
file4.zip 
     #contains 
     file4.scsv
     file4_key.scsv
     file4_flag.scsv
file5.zip 
     #contains 
     file5.scsv
```

I'm quite new to bash/linux, so I tried following [How to zip files with same name but different extension?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417163/how-to-zip-files-with-same-name-but-different-extension) as an example, but this assumes the files have precisely the same name before the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming that

```
files2.zip 
     #contains 
     files2.scsv
filass3.zip 
     #contains 
     filass3.scsv
```

is acceptable; otherwise you’d have to clarify the file name transformation rules.

```bash
for file in *.scsv; do
  if [[ ! "$file" =~ _ ]]; then
    base="${file%.scsv}"
    zip -9 "${base}.zip" "${file}" "${base}_*.scsv"
  fi
done
```

will look at each file with a `.scsv` extension, and if its name *doesn’t* contain “_”, create a ZIP file named after it (with `.zip` instead of `.scsv`), containing the file and any other files with the same prefix following by an underscore.

There’s a small trick here: I’m relying on `zip`’s wildcard handling instead of the shell’s, to avoid dealing with issues when there is no other file to add. `zip` will warn about this but won’t abort.